# How to enter a long and not-a-string data into the argument?

Tags: python

I have a problem with Python and need your help.
Take a look at this code:

```
import os
os.chdir('''C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Automate_the_Boring_Stuff_onlimematerials_v.2\\automate_online-materials\\example.xlsx''')
```

The `os.chdir()` did not work because the directory I put in between the `'''`  and `'''` is considered as raw string. Note that a line is no more than 125 characters, so I have to make a new line.

So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can split your statement into multiple lines by using the backslash `\` to indicate that a statement is continued on the new line.

```
message = 'This message will not generate an error because \
it was split by using the backslash on your \
keyboard'

print(message)
```

Output

> This message will not generate an error because it was split by using the backslash on your keyboard

Comment: This is new to me. Thank you. I gonna try it.

Answer (score 1):

Lines can be longer than 125 characters, but you should probably avoid that. You have a few solutions:

```py
x = ('hi'
     'there')
# x is now the string "hithere"
os.chdir('hi'
         'there') # does a similar thing (os.chdir('hithere'))
```

You could also set up a variable:

```
root_path = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop"
filepath = "other\\directories" # why not just rename it though
os.chdir(os.path.join(root_path, filepath))
```

Do these work for you?

I'm also curious why you have to chdir there; if it's possible, you should just run the python script from that directory.

Comment: Your solution works.The rename solution is also so simple yet excellent. I probably gonna use it some day. I am writing some code involved Excel and those files require to be in the current working directory. Thank you!

Comment: I do it again and somehow your two solution didn't work. However, the error occur the same for two solution. It seem like the problem is not only the long directory. I am writing some code involved Excel and those files require to be in the current working directory. this is the line from the system: NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\ATBSmaterial\\yeah\\example.xlsx'
Hope you can help.

Comment: You cannot chdir into a file, only a directory - so get rid of `example.xlsx` from your chdir call. Updating answer.

Comment: Yup! Mark as right answer when you're all set if it worked for you :)